# How do I catch Revit errors in Revit API?

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I'm trying to catch an error displayed in Revit to perform some handle operations. Error is due to the connection of points as shown in the image below.
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3ctP.png)
This is what I have tested with so far.

```
try
{
    var pipe = Pipe.Create(doc, firstPipeType.Id, level.Id, startCon, 
    pathXyz[0]);
}
catch (Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InvalidOperationException e)
{
    message = e.Message;
    return Result. Failed;
}
```

Based on the documentation, I am trying to catch and handle the following exception.
"Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Thrown when the new pipe fails to connect with the connector."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is different from the exception. The instructions on how to handle the error message are provided by [The Building Coder](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) in the topic group on [Detecting and Handling Dialogues and Failures](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.32).